# How to set specific URLs to use VPN connection for DNS (Windows)?

Tags: windows, vpn, dns, pptp, split-tunnel

I have a PPTP VPN connection named "myvpn"

```
PPP adapter myvpn:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 4274:35b2:be80::b4d3:97b0%65
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.10.10.20
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

(Associated DNS servers to the VPN are `192.168.123.11` and `192.168.123.12`)

### **Problem:**

With the VPN, I can **only** access my work website `app.zzz.com` which corresponding IP is `192.168.123.102`.

And without VPN, no DNS server resolves that URL.

### **Question:**

Is it possible to make Windows **only** resolve `app.zzz.com` through myvpn connection?

and only route the corresponding IP through the VPN?

Comment: By default, send all traffic to the remote gateway is enabled. If you disable this, it will try both your home network and the remote server. It will work as long as the remote network is not in the same ip range. https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2263587-how-to-use-local-gateway-instead-of-remote-gateway-in-vpn-connection

Comment: @LPChip No, uncheck that option make every DNS request to not use VPN.

Comment: Yes, but if it can't find app.zzz.com on your local network, it will then try the VPN still.

Comment: @LPChip No, it doesn't. I get the error "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" on edge.

Comment: On the VPN connection, in IPv4, go to advanced settings, and on the DNS tab, specify the ip address of the DNS server that can resolve app.zzz.com and it should work. Do not setup DNS from the Ipv4 settings itself, somehow that doesn't work, even though that page gets filled if you do it the right way.

Comment: @LPChip not worked. I used "192.168.123.11" and also select "register this connection in dns list" but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.
first uncheck "use default gateway on remote network" to let all requests bypass VPN connection.

Then with below command, let all `192.168.123.x` requests (including DNS requests) to pass through VPN.

```
Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "myvpn" -DestinationPrefix "192.168.123.0/24"
```

Edit:
If you export the rasdial.pbk file and use it on another system, It's OK and everything work. Because route rules are saved on the pbk file connection.

Edit2: I think this method is for win 8+ but I found another might work for older windows.
https://medium.com/@ATheCoder/how-to-use-split-tunneling-for-your-vpn-on-windows-10-85e76635914d

Comment: That was gonna be my next suggestion. Weird that just setting the DNS did not work.

Comment: @LPChip Yeah, look like there is a problem with prioritizing gateways.